# Laravel eloquent gives array of numbers, instead of integers

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to return id's as a string and pass them via api (using for select later)

Using Laravel resouces:

```
public function toArray($request)
{

    return [
        'speciality' => $this->specialities()->pluck('speciality_id')
    ];
}
```

and it returns an array of numbers, like:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

How can I convert them within eloquent query and return like a string?

```
["1", "3", "5", "7"]
```

Comment: that doesn't make sense, why you need id as string?? Could you please show the usability of this data where you need this as string.

Comment: to use for edit page, I've got form select field, and it don't accept array of numbers, only strings (vue js)

Comment: You could map it over the [`strval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) function. `$this->specialities()->pluck('speciality_id')->map('strval')`

Comment: @Dencker this is better approach, but gives an error:
`strval() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

Comment: @gileneusz Ah. It's only a warning and can be safely ignored or suppressed. If you wanna play by the book, you could do `->map(function($item){ return strval($item); })` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit **awful**, but if have no choice then 
[cast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#attribute-casting) it to string

```
protected $casts=[
    'speciality_id'=>'string'
];
```

Comment: Seems awful to cast a primary key to a string globally just to make a Vue component accept it.

Comment: I will later fix it not to work on primary key, just add new column on table. It's  very bad practice, what I'm doing now, I know

Answer (score 2):

You could `loop` through the array, `cast` it to string and add to `new array` as it is only required for this `specific` case.

```
$a = [1, 3, 5, 7];
$b = array();
foreach($a as $as)
        $b[] = (string)$as;

return $b;
```

Or better use `array_map()` -

```
$a = array_map(function($value){
        return (string) $value;
}, $a);
```

Comment: thank you, this seems better than casting, I'll try it

Comment: casting is good for all cases but for particular case you may try transform https://laracasts.com/series/incremental-api-development/episodes/4 and put this logic there

Comment: I'll see what happens on syncing many to many relationship table after this casting